# Request for Reference: BRST formalism/transformations

Tags: resource-recommendations, symmetry, gauge-invariance, constrained-dynamics, brst

Could anyone please suggest a **very basic paper/reference/literature on BRST symmetry/formalism** that requires rudimentary knowledge of Dirac's method for dealing with constrained systems and generation of gauge transformations by first-class constraints?

By very basic I mean as basic and pedagogic as possible for this subject.

Comment: Polchinski's treatment in his string theory books is ideal, and sidesteps the Dirac formalism completely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

J.W. van Holten's "Aspects of BRST Quantization" [arXiv:hep-th/0201124](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201124/) might be what you're looking for...